# d3js drag right button

Tags: canvas, d3.js, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

I am building hex map with canvas. I have to draw some details with right mouse btn.
I use d3js to zoom and move canvas. Problem is I can`t draw correct with right button.

I`ve created simple example to show what is wrong.

```html
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <div id="map_canvas">
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
<script>
var width = $('#map_canvas').width(),
    height = 700;
var ctx;

function zooms() {
    if(d3.event.sourceEvent.button !== 0) {
        return
    }else {

        ofsetx = d3.event.translate[0];
        ofsety = d3.event.translate[1];
        scale = d3.event.scale;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        ctx.translate(d3.event.translate[0], d3.event.translate[1]);
        ctx.scale(d3.event.scale, d3.event.scale);
        draw()
        ctx.restore();
    }
}

function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([-2, 10])
    .on("zoom", zooms)

$(function() {
    ctx = d3.select("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("ofsetx", 0)
    .attr("ofsety", 0)
    .call(zoom)
    .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
    .on("contextmenu", function (d, i) {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
    })
    .node().getContext("2d");
    draw();
});
</script>
```

1. Try to drag canvas with right button.
2. After it try to drag a little with left one.

You`ll see, that first drag has worked but not drawed.

I don`t want to make any move, zoom and etc with pressed right button. Please, help

Answer (score 1):

Check the `mousedown` and kill the zoom/pan if it's the wrong button:

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <div id="map_canvas">
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
<script>
var width = $('#map_canvas').width(),
    height = 700;
var ctx;

function zooms() {
    ofsetx = d3.event.translate[0];
    ofsety = d3.event.translate[1];
    scale = d3.event.scale;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.translate(d3.event.translate[0], d3.event.translate[1]);
    ctx.scale(d3.event.scale, d3.event.scale);
    draw()
     ctx.restore();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([-2, 10])
    .on("zoom", zooms)

$(function() {
    ctx = d3.select("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("ofsetx", 0)
    .attr("ofsety", 0)
    .on("mousedown", function(){
      if (d3.event.button !== 0){
        d3.event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
    })
    .call(zoom)
    .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
    .on("contextmenu", function (d, i) {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
    })
    .node().getContext("2d");
    draw();
});
</script>
```